# Does importScripts pause worker thread execution? (Dedicated worker)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, web-worker, webapi

The [WebAPI specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) mention that importScripts loads scripts **synchronously**

[Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/refs/heads/main/blink/renderer/core/workers/worker_global_scope.cc#375)'s the chromium code which implements this.

However, my understanding is that web apis run in a separate thread pool. Since importScripts is a web api offering to begin with, it should run separately from the worker thread and not pause worker execution. Then what does synchronously mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question, because I have an insight)

There are two facts pointed out in the question :

1. `importScripts` is synchronous
2. `importSripts` does not run on the worker thread (i.e. it runs outside the V8 runtime)

My misconception was these two facts are contradictory. They're not!
Being a web api, it is implemented as native browser code. But that does not guarantee concurrency.
Another example is when you call `XmlHttpRequest.send()` with `synchronous = true`.

[image]

Bottomline : running separately from the JS runtime thread does not guarantee asynchronous.